# Deklination nach einer Zahl

Tags: declension

> "2002 gab es noch 14235 dieser Orte in Deutschland." ( Deutsch
>   perfekt 3/2019, S. 67)

Warum nicht "14235 diese Orte"? Welche Regeln gelten für Deklination nach einer Zahl?

Answer (score 7):

Deine Frage hat mit Zahlen nichts zu tun. Setze *viele* statt der Zahl ein, und alles andere bleibt gleich.

Ich markiere mal das Akkusativobjekt des Verbs *geben*:

> Es gab noch **fünf Orte**.
>
> Es gab noch **fünf**.
>
> Es gab noch **fünf** *der Orte*.

Im letzten Beispiel ist *der Orte* eine Genitivergänzung des Akkusativobjekts. Solche Ergänzungen werden immer dann benutzt, wenn man weitere Fakten unterbringen will.

> Es gab noch fünf dieser Orte.

Hier ist es der zusätzliche Fingerzeit mittels des Demonstrativpronomens *dieser*. Und *dieser* lautet im Genitiv Plural eben auch *dieser*.

Comment: Wie würde man nach dem Genitivobjekt fragen? *Wovon/Wessen/Welcher gab es noch fünf*?

Comment: Es handelt sich nicht um ein Genitivobjekt, sondern um eine Genitivergänzung des Akkusativobjekts.

Comment: Ja gut und wie fragt man danach?

Comment: Vgl. übrigens auch *dergestalt* vs *sogennant*, Niederländisch *door*, den determinativ *der* ...

Comment: Normalerweise sollte man auf *wen?* schon die Antwort *fünf dieser Orte* erhalten, aber wenn die Antwort nur *fünf* lautet, fordert das die Frage *wovon?* heraus.

Comment: Wessen gab es fünf? – Dieser Orte.

Answer (score 0):

Vergleich

- im 16Jh. Brachten `NOM` Reisende `AKK` Tomaten nach Europa.
- `NOM` Die gezüchteten Nachkommen `GEN` dieser Tomaten wurden gezielt selektiert.
- Heutzutage bieten `NOM` Händler `AKK` die größten Tomaten zum Verkauf.
- `NOM` Ich sah heute `AKK` die größten Tomaten `GEN` dieser Händler. Das waren `NOM` die größten Tomaten `GEN` Ihrer Sorte, `NOM` die Größten `?` aller Zeiten.
- **Ich kaufte `AKK` ein Dutzend (zwölf) `GEN` dieser Tomaten.** `GEN DET` Deren Geschmack war gut.
- `NOM` Das Geheimnis `GEN` des Erfolgs `GEN` dieser Sorte ist mir nicht klar.
- `NOM` Ich werde bei `DAT` dem nächsten günstigen Angebot `GEN INDEF` solcher Tomaten werde ich wieder zugreifen.

Die Kurze Antwort: *diese* ist akkusativ, so wie die Zahl im Beispielsatz. Dagegen ist *dieser Orte* ein Prädikat, das die Zahl einer Menge zuordnet (genauer: einer Übermenge), aus der die Anzahl entnommen wird. Die Syntax folgt der Analogie zu den oben genannten Beispielen.

Die Beispiele lassen einiges erahnen. Hier wurde aber nur gefragt *warum nicht?*. Das Paradigma ist recht komplex. Warum es nicht gerade *zehn solcher Orte* oder *zehn der Orte* heißt sind eng verwandte Fragen, denen aber besser ein anderes Mal auf den Grund gegangen wird.

Comment: Es wäre schön, wenn in einer Antwort auf diese Frage mindestens einmal der Begriff "Genitiv" fallen würde. Ist das nicht der Fall, ist es leider keine Antwort.

Comment: @tofro Also ich hab gezählt und bin auf acht mal Genitiv gekommen, wenn auch als `GEN` geschrieben. Ja, könnte man noch erläutern. Aber mit den anderen Fall-Kennzeichnungen wär's mir gleich verständlich.

Comment: @tofro wenn du keine anderen Sorgen hast, bin ich ja beruhigt